# Receiving Empty Fields after applying RequiredValidator in asp.net forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am facing problem where in my form I have given requiredfield validation and it is working fine as per my testing but still receiving back to back email with empty field. I have textbox in which user have to fill their contact number & submit the form which comes to my mail ID. I have tested 100 of time and everytime it doesn't accept form submission if number field is empty but don't know why I am receiving mail with empty values. Is there any hack from which validation can be overcome? Following is code I am using

```
<asp:TextBox ID="callBackNumber2" runat="server" CssClass="field-pitch" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="r1" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="callBackNumber2" CssClass="validator" 
ErrorMessage="Please enter call back number" style="position:relative; 
top:-20px" ValidationGroup="callBack2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <span class="field-title">Nature Of Request</span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="callBackNature" runat="server" CssClass="field-pitch">
                <asp:ListItem>Information about product</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Need a Price Quote</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Existing Order</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Button ID="makeCallBack2" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="gen-button" ValidationGroup="callBack2" />
```

Button Click Event

```
if (Page.IsValid) {
    try {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
        mail.To.Add("main@abc.com");
        mail.CC.Add("sample@abc.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress(mailTo.Text);
        mail.Subject = "Call Back Request From " + callBackNumber2.Text + "";
        mail.Body = "Call back Number - " + callBackNumber2.Text + "<br />Nature Of Request - " + callBackNature.SelectedItem.ToString + "<br />Source - " + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "<br />IP - " + ipaddress + "";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpServer.Port = 25;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailTo.Text, mailPassword.Text);
        SmtpServer.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        mpCallBack.Show();
        callBackResponse.Visible = true;
        callBackContent.Visible = false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use if clause at the beginning of your codes like this;

```
if (callBackNumber2.Text != string.Empty)
{ your codes }
```

Comment: I am not looking for any alternate solutions.